# react-native android build failing: error: cannot find symbol variable FirebaseCrash

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

Literary i can't make a stable apk for the last 2 weeks, this driving me nuts!

[image: error]

I have followed the `react-native-firebase` documentation 1:1

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "runiPhone5s": "react-native run-ios --simulator=\"iPhone 5s\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@exponent/react-native-action-sheet": "^0.2.1",
    "@remobile/react-native-refresh-infinite-listview": "github:remobile/react-native-refresh-infinite-listview#pull/8/head",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-mixin": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.48.3",
    "react-native-barcode-scanner-universal": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-deprecated-custom-components": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "git://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob.git#b6c6f9a199e9530221f3b89fb7a219db324d0e83",
    "react-native-firebase": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-gifted-listview": "github:faridsafi/react-native-gifted-listview#pull/51/head",
    "react-native-loading-container": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-mail": "3.0.3",
    "react-native-maps": "0.16.4",
    "react-native-onesignal": "3.0.5",
    "react-native-permissions": "1.0.0",
    "react-native-share": "^1.0.13",
    "superagent": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

My `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
...
android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.adpagesgo"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            multiDexEnabled true
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
...


    dependencies {
        compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
        compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

        compile project(':react-native-share')
        compile project(':react-native-mail')
        //compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"

        compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
        compile(project(':react-native-maps')) {
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-analytics'
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-location'
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-gcm'
        }
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.0"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.0"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.0"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.0"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.0"

        compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
                    transitive = false
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-analytics'
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-location'
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-gcm'
            }
        compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0"
        compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.2.0"
        compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.2.0"

        compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    }

    // Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
    // puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
    task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
        from configurations.compile
        into 'libs'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


My `android/build.gradle`:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

At this point any idea would be welcome, how can it not find the dependency when it's included and compiled..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of `react-native-firebase` and google-play-services versions must be the same inside `android/app/build.gradle`!

Android studio provides great tips on this.